# ¿Cómo solucionar el fatal error Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy realizando un formulario para añadir usuarios a un sistema de información para clase. Para este debo relacionar dos tablas (agrego las columnas de cada tabla):

usuarios_

- id_usuario_ (primary key)
- nombre_usuario_
- nombre_completo_
- contraseña_
- rol_id_ (esta es la llave foránea)
- descripcion_

roles_

- id_rol_ (primary key)
- rol_

Bueno, el problema está que al enviar el formulario me marca el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`curvas_de_papel_`.`usuarios_`, CONSTRAINT `usuarios__ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`rol_id_`) REFERENCES `roles_` (`id_rol_`) ON UPDATE CASCADE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\papeleria\Views\CRUD\crear\añadirusuario.view.php:27 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\papeleria\Views\CRUD\crear\añadirusuario.view.php(27): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'INSERT INTO `us...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\papeleria\Views\CRUD\crear\añadirusuario.view.php on line 27

Mi código es el siguiente:

```html
<?php
  if(!empty($_POST))
  {
      $alert='';
      if(empty($_POST['nombreuser']) || empty($_POST['contraseñauser']) || empty($_POST['iduser']) || empty($_POST['nombrecompleted']) || empty($_POST['tipuser']) || empty($_POST['descripcionuser']))
      {
        $alert='<p class="msg_error"> Todos los campos son obligatorios </p>';
      }else{

          include("/xampp/htdocs/papeleria/db.php");

          $id = $_POST['iduser'];
          $user = $_POST['nombreuser'];
          $nombrec = $_POST['nombrecompleted'];
          $contraseña = $_POST['contraseñauser'];
          $rol = $_POST['rol'];
          $descripcion = $_POST['descripcionuser'];

          $query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM usuarios_ WHERE id_usuario_ = '$id' OR nombre_usuario_ = '$user'");
          $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

          if($result > 0){
            $alert='<p class="msg_error"> El id o usuario ya existen </p>';
          }else{
            
            $query_insert = mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO `usuarios_`(`id_usuario_`, `nombre_usuario_`, `nombre_completo_`, `contraseña_`, `rol_id_`, `descripcion_`) 
                                                                      VALUES ('$id','$user','$nombrec','$contraseña','$rol','$descripcion')");
                  if($query_insert){
                    $alert='<p class="msg_save"> Usuario creado correctamente </p>';
                  }else{
                    $alert='<p class="msg_error"> Error al crear usuario </p>';
                  }
          }
      }
  }


?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="\papeleria\Assets\css\">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/papeleria/assets/css/compras.css" th:href="@/papeleria/assets/css/compras.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <title>Nuevo Usuario</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <?php
        include("/xampp/htdocs/papeleria/Views/template/header.view.php")
    ?>
  </header>
  <section class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="card shadow p-4" style="background-color: #d4c1d7; position:fixed; height:510px; top: 90px; left:260px;">
        <div class="form" style="position: flex; overflow-y: scroll;">
        <div class="mb-4 d-flex justify-content-start align-items-center">
              <h4>  <i class="bi bi-person-plus-fill"></i> &nbsp; Nuevo Usuario</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="alert"><?php echo isset($alert) ? $alert : ''; ?></div>
            <div class="mb-4 d-flex justify-content-start align-items-center">
              
            <form role="form" method="post" action="">
            <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="iduser" class="col-form-label col-sm-3"> ID </label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="number" name="iduser" id="iduser" class="form-control"  tabindex="2">
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="nombreuser" class="col-form-label col-sm-3"> Nombre </label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" name="nombreuser" id="nombreuser" class="form-control"  tabindex="2">
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
      <br>
            <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="contraseñauser" class="col-form-label col-sm-3"> Contraseña </label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="password" name="contraseñauser" id="contraseñauser" class="form-control"  tabindex="2">
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
      <br>
            <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="nombrecompleted" class="col-form-label col-sm-3"> Nombre Completo </label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" name="nombrecompleted" id="nombrecompleted" class="form-control"  tabindex="2">
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
      <br>
            <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="descripcionuser" class="col-form-label col-sm-3"> Descripción </label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" name="descripcionuser" id="descripcionuser" class="form-control"  tabindex="2">
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
      <br>
          
      <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group row">
                <div >
                            <label for="rol" class="col-form-label col-sm-3">Rol</label>
                            <?php
                              include("/xampp/htdocs/papeleria/db.php");
                              $query_rol = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM roles_");
                              $result_rol = mysqli_num_rows($query_rol);
                            
                            ?>
                            <select name="rol">
                              <?php
                                if($result_rol > 0)
                                {
                                  while ($rol = mysqli_fetch_array($query_rol)) {
                                ?>
                                  <option value="<?php $rol["id_rol_"]; ?>"><?php echo $rol["rol_"] ?></option>
                              <?php
              
                                }
                              }
                            ?>
                         </select>
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
     <br>
       <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-12">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
           <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Permitir editar los movimientos almacenados</label>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
   <br>
          
          <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                    <div >
                                <label for="apellido" class="col-form-label col-sm-3"> Cuadres de caja</label>
                                <select name="tipuser">
                                  <option value="adm"> Todos los cuadres </option>
                                  <option value="emp"> Ningun cuadre </option>
                                  <option value="emp"> Sólo los propios </option>
                             </select>
                </div>
             </div>
         </div>
</div>
         <br>
          
          <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                    <div >
                                <label for="apellido" class="col-form-label col-sm-3">Permitir editar</label>
                                <select name="tipuser">
                                  <option value="adm"> Cantidades y Valores  </option>
                                  <option value="emp"> Cantidades </option>
                                  <option value="emp"> Valores</option>
                             </select>
                </div>
             </div>
         </div>
         <br>
           
        <div class="row">
        <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-left justify-content-md-end">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6"><input type="submit" value="Añadir Usuario" class="btn btn-secundary btn-block btn-lg" tabindex="7"
                title="Guardar datos ingresados"></div>
        </div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
<footer>
      <?php
        include("/xampp/htdocs/papeleria/Views/template/footer.view.php")
      ?>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Antes he realizado una prueba sin usar una relación entre las tablas, y efectivamente el formulario guardaba los datos en la tabla de usuarios_, pero al momento de establecer la llave foránea creo que lo he jodido. Y si intento insertar datos desde phpmyadmin se ejecuta la consulta correctamente.

En realidad le agradecería mucho su ayuda, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el código que has puesto le falta el **`echo`** en `<option value="<?php $rol["id_rol_"]; ?>">`

La línea debería ser

```
<option value="<?php echo $rol["id_rol_"]; ?>"><?php echo $rol["rol_"] ?></option>
```

Por lo tanto,todas las opciones están con valor vacío o algo similar por lo que intenta insertar el vacío como `rol_id_`

---

No entro en otros temas como los nombres de campos en diferentes tablas, el peligro de no preparar las sentencias SQL contra la inyección, mezclar menos el php entre tramos html, etc. Pero el motivo del fallo por el que preguntas es ese.

Comment: esto no es una respuesta, esto bien pudo ser un comentario o sugerencia.